# how to enable landscape mode on a Kindle?

Tags: kindle, formatting, firmware, customization, screens

Running `Firmware 5.8.9.0.1` on a seventh generation Kindle.  I had landscape enabled before but can't find it now.  The `paperwhite` [directions](http://www.liabelle.me/how-to-read-ebooks-in-landscape-mode-on-your-kindle-paperwhite/) don't work as there's no such option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Open a book.
2. Tap **Aa**.
3. Select **Page > Orientation**